# Serialize objects into a dat file

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist

So i have this array list of objects i would like to store into a dat file in binary format .

the objectA class has this constructor

```
public ObjectA(String aString,int aNumber ,String[] sampleA){
    this.aString = aString;
    this.aNumber = aNumber;
    this.sampleA= sampleA;
}
```

in another class file i instantiated this on the class and have filled the arraylist with ObjectA objects

```
      private static ArrayList<ObjectA> objectA = new ArrayList<ObjectA>();
```

and i have this method

```
 private static void createFile() {
    System.out.println("Creating file...");

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("file.dat");
        ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);

            for (ObjectA o : objectA) {
                objectOut.writeObject(o); //write the object
            }

            objectOut.close(); //then close the writer

        }CATCH EXCEPTIONS***************{}

}
```

However i caught this error when trying to run this
Error on createFile()! java.io.NotSerializableException: ObjectA in the trycatch
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ObjectA` has to implement the [java.io.Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface.

```
public ObjectA implements Serializable {

}
```

This is not the only valid approach, though.

Implementing [java.io.Externalizable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) is valid, as well. The difference is that `java.io.Serializable` is known as **marker interface** (e.g. the interface doesn't provide methods for implementing), while `java.io.Externalizable` forces you to implement two methods and so provides the necessary means for implementing a custom serialization mechanism.

```
public class ObjectA implements Externalizable {
    @Override
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) { ... }

    @Override
    public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) { ... }
}
```